# Can I safely restore a Scylla backup from 1.6 in scylla 2.0 or 2.1

Tags: scylla

I'm reading the documentation on Scylla's upgrade procedures (
reading the dochttp://docs.scylladb.com/upgrade/upgrade-guide-from-2.0-to-2.1-ubuntu/ for example), and I'm seeing the standard "Stair-Step" path is required from 1.6->2.0->2.1, etc. 
As a general question, if I have a backup from  an older version of scylla 1.6 (or 1.4 or 1.5), is can I load that into a newer release and  the data be migrated automatically? Is there a manual process or a tool that I can use?

Or is the only way to get data from 1.6 to 2.1 to load data into a 1.6 database, do a 1.6->1.7 upgrade, a 1.7->2.0 upgrade, then a 2.0->2.1 upgrade.

Answer (score 7):

You can restore older backups into newer versions just fine. The stair-step procedure that is listed is intended for online migrations (without downtime). If you are doing offline migrations, you can skip versions just fine.

Note that there is a caveat with that: if the tables you are moving come from a different cluster (if you completely wiped out this cluster, for instance) then you have to be mindful of the token ranges of each node when copying the files: just because you had 5 nodes before and have 5 nodes now, it doesn't mean that those nodes own the same token ranges.

Aside from that small caveat, you are good to go!

Comment: What is best procedure/ best practices for changing token ranges in a reinstantiated cluster (same cluster name, but went from 5 nodes to 4, or 4 nodes to 5)?

Comment: if you changed the number of nodes, then I don't recommend playing with the token ranges because the result will be very imbalanced. If you are keeping the same amount of nodes, look at the `initial_token` option